# In my react app, the POST method is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to react and have created a simple react app. The screenshot of how my app looks like is below:

[image]

In the Add to Cart button, I have implemented a function for the POST method. But, the error is whenever I click on the button, nothing appears on the console and I guess the POST method is not working. Only a empty array is seen on the console as below:

[image]

My PDP.js code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";

class PDP extends Component {
    state = {
        pdpCategory: []
    };

    fetchData = id => {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3030/product/` + id)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.express.catalogEntryView);
                this.setState({ pdpCategory: response.data.express.catalogEntryView });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });


        var data = new FormData();
        const payload = {

            id: this.props.match.params.uniqueID,
            description: this.props.match.params.longDescription

        };
        data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));

        fetch('http://localhost:3030/posts', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
        console.log(data)

    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        let currentId = this.props.match.params.id;
        let previousId = prevProps.match.params.id;
        if (currentId !== previousId) {
            this.fetchData(currentId);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.fetchData(id);
    }

    doSomething = function (e) {
        alert('it works!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        const { pdpCategory } = this.state;
        console.log(pdpCategory);
        const picUrl = "https://149.129.128.3:8443";

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <form onSubmit={this.doSomething}>
                            {pdpCategory &&
                                pdpCategory.map(pdpList => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={pdpList.uniqueID} className="col-md-4">
                                            <h2 key={pdpList.uniqueID} />

                                            <img className="pdpImage " src={picUrl + pdpList.thumbnail} />
                                            <p>
                                                Price : {pdpList.price[0].value}{" "}
                                                {pdpList.price[0].currency}
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                Description: {pdpList.longDescription}
                                            </p>
                                            <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PDP;
```

Also, I have used node js to to fetch the API's for the react app.

server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;//import it here
const app = express();

app.use(cors());


app.post('/posts', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });


app.get('/topCategory', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1", (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });



 app.get('/category/:id', (req, res) => {
     var id = req.params.id;
     console.log(req.params.id)
    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/productview/byCategory/"+id, (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });


 app.get('/product/:id', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.params.id)
   var client = new Client();

   // direct way
   client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/productview/byId/"+id, (data, response) => {
    res.send({ express: data });
   });
});


const port = 3030;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port${port}`));
```

Can someone please help me on this as to where I'm getting wrong. Is it because I have configured in the server wrongly or because my event handler is not working. I would be grateful if somebody gives me an insight regarding this.

Comment: Where is the empty array?  Can you expand the ```0``` key on that object and send another screenshot of what it contains?

Comment: Please share your `this.onSubmit` method

Comment: @JonathanRys I have updated  my question and as asked by you I have shared the screen shot

Comment: @rashad I have changed my code a bit and on clicking the button a alert is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Your form calls `this.onSubmit`:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

And your component doesn't have an `onSubmit` method.

Comment: I have now added the function

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy Ray mentioned, you're missing an onSubmit function in your component. Also, you need to bind the function scope to the internal scope of your component class. Instead of this `<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>` try this `<form onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>`. Alternatively you could bind it in your component's constructor like this `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);`. See [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

I assume your `onSubmit` function would look something like this:

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // make network call or whatever
}
```

Comment: `onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>` Good heavens why? You're creating a function that adds no value.

Comment: I have updated my code. Now a alert is triggered on clicking. But, I guess POST is still not working. Can you please help me a bit

Comment: @Dave Newton You could do it either way. Adding an inline function is a way to tell the whole story in the component template. Adding it in the constructor is cumbersome and disconnected, IMO. You don't have to remember to go up to the constructor and add a new line every time you want to add a new event.

Comment: @Dave Newton the real question is why do we have to bind the function at all. This is an inefficiency with React. It's boilerplate that the dev should not have to worry about. Look at similar frameworks and you won't see it. Vue, for example, lets you call the function directly `onclick="onSubmit"`.

Comment: @colefner  I guess that now I changed my code.But, on clicking it should hit the API, but its not happening.

Comment: @colefner If you use arrow functions, you don't have to bind it (explicitly). But framework wars are boring, so *shrug*. The problem with inlining is that it adds a layer of inefficiency which may or may not be an actual issue depending on number of renders, number of components, etc.

Comment: Hi @shaswatiBhattacharyya I would confirm that the endpoint is working independently of the UI. You could do this by writing a test for it (the `superagent` npm package is handy for this) or by calling it manually with a client like Postman.

Comment: @colefner But my doubt is by clicking on the button, it should do the POST method. How would I achieve that

Comment: @DaveNewton Framework wars are boring. Can't help having opinions about them though. Having 0 opinions would be even more boring :-) I've worked in both, but more in Vue. Still getting used to React. Glad to know about the arrow function approach.

Comment: @shaswatiBhattacharyya You could use Chrome developer tools and set a breakpoint in your component to confirm the `onSubmit` function is working properly. Or just `console.log` out a message. Then watch the Network tab of the dev tools to ensure the request is being sent out as expected. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/